# MKMapView Memory Issues

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, mapkit, mkmapview

So I am aware that MKMapView has memory issues so to get around it I have been using a static var that means one MKMapView is used throughout my app.  The issue I am having is that when I call the function I have created to update the map, I see the memory increase if the location changes.  Take the simple case below.  I have a MK Map View and a UIButton that when tapped, moves the map's center location. Each time it is tapped the memory usage increases and holds 2-5 MB higher than before tapping. Is there a way to prevent this memory increase?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapView.setCamera(MKMapCamera(lookingAtCenter: coordinates[0], fromDistance: 5000, pitch: 45, heading: 0), animated: false)
}

@IBAction func updateMap(_ sender: Any) {
    mapView.showsCompass = true
    
    let correctedIndex = (selectedIndex % 7)
    
    let location = coordinates[correctedIndex]

    mapView.camera.centerCoordinate = location
    selectedIndex += 1
}

var selectedIndex = 1

var coordinates = [
    CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 53.27, longitude: -7.77),
    CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.63, longitude: -7.76),
    CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.34, longitude: -2.16),
    CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 50.27, longitude: 4.02),
    CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 50, longitude: 13),
    CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 50, longitude: 14),
    CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 50, longitude: 15),
    CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 50, longitude: 16),
]
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out the answer is simple, yet a little irritating.

Adding the following lines of code to updateMap prior to moving the camera fixes the problem (probably would work better after, but I don't feel like going back right now and doing further testing...).

```
mapView.mapType = MKMapType.hybrid
mapView.mapType = MKMapType.standard
```

Apparently changing the map type clears the cached map tiles.  Now the memory increases and decreases with the number of features on the map.

Note: I don't know the true author of the fix, but I found it here:
https://www.programmersought.com/article/6006585971/